# Question on using a dictionary to define answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a python script where depending on the keywords present in the question asked a specific answer is sent.

i.e If a question is asked that contains any word from dictionary A and specific answer is returned and then if the question contains any word from dictionary B a different answer is returned.

I am currently using an if else stack and stating the keywords manually but would like to place them in a dictionary.

Comment: Please provide any code you have attempted it will make answering your question a whole lot easier.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your code and let us know where you got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this, where you loop through each dictionary checking if a keyword is in either one, and if it is, returning the corresponding answer

```py
keywords_A = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
keywords_B = {'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6}

def get_answer(question):
    for keyword in keywords_A:
        if keyword in question:
            return keywords_A[keyword]
    for keyword in keywords_B:
         if keyword in question:
            return keywords_B[keyword]

get_answer('What is one written as?')
>>> 1
get_answer('What is five written as?')
>>> 5
```